# python mechanize handle two parameters with same name

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, mechanize

I'm logging into a page where they oddly have a form input called `login_email` and two form inputs called `login_password`. I need to set the value of both but the straightforward call `form['login_password']` throws an error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
    return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3183, in _find_control
    raise AmbiguityError("more than one control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.AmbiguityError: more than one control matching name 'login_password'
```

I just need to find a way to submit `form['login_password'] = "Password"` and `form['login_password'] = "monkeybutler"` at the same time.  I'm not seeing a variable in the `Browser` object to change the POST data params.

Any suggestions? 
Here's what I tried without success:

```
# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# Let's search
br.form['login_email'] = 'mommajane@gmail.com'

#my_fields = br.form.fields.select
#my_fields[0].login_password = "Password"
#my_fields[1].login_password = "123qwerty"
br.form['login_password']= ['Password','123qwerty']

br.submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are facing two fields with the same name, id and so on, you must use a little workaround, altough its not very clean

First I have defined a simple html file for that example since I did not know the URL you used:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>foo</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>bar</h1>

<form action="input_text.htm">
  <p>name:<br><input name="name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></p>
  <p>sec_name:<br><input name="sec_name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="40"></p>
  <p>sec_name:<br><input name="sec_name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="40"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Afterwards I was able to insert values into those fields quick and dirty by using this python code:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> browser = mechanize.Browser()
>>> browser.open("file:///home/foo/index.html")
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x229a7e8 whose wrapped ...
>>> browser.select_form(nr=0)
>>> name = 'foo'
>>> for control in browser.form.controls:
...     if control.name == 'sec_name':
...             control.value = name
...             name = 'bar'
... 
>>> for control in browser.form.controls:
...     print control
... 
<TextControl(name=)>
<TextControl(sec_name=foo)>
<TextControl(sec_name=bar)>
>>>
```

It`s not nice but it works. Hope that helped.