# ClientForm.AmbiguityError: more than one control matching name

Tags: python, mechanize

I am new programming in python and recently trying to login to private website with mechanize;I read similar questions like:
[How to bypass Mechanize "AmbiguityError" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854763/how-to-bypass-mechanize-ambiguityerror-in-python), [python mechanize handle two parameters with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035713/python-mechanize-handle-two-parameters-with-same-name), however non of these could help and there is no feedback on solution for the second link. As far as I've read, using br.select_form(nr=0) should be enough to select the first form however I am still stuck; I've tried as well changing br.select_form(name of form) and br.form.find_control() with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_control'; all options without success.
Below code and the list of forms can be found. Support is appreciated. Thanks

this is the code used:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form["username"]= 'Myusername'
br.form["password"]= 'Mypassword'
br.submit()
```

these are the forms:

```
<HiddenControl(smauthreason=0) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(clientfp=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(smtryno=0) (readonly)>
<TextControl(username=)>
<PasswordControl(password=)>
<TextControl(username=)>
<PasswordControl(password=)>
<TextControl(username=)>
<PasswordControl(password=)>
<IgnoreControl(submitFrm=<None>)>
<HiddenControl(SMAGENTNAME= "deleted by me") (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(POSTPRESERVATIONDATA=) (readonly)>>
```

This is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Documents/JMARTINEZ/My Various/PythonPrograms/Mechanize.py",line 77, in <module> br.form["username"]= username
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ClientForm.py", line 2895, in __setitem__control = self.find_control(name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ClientForm.py", line 3222, in find_control return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ClientForm.py", line 3304, in _find_control raise AmbiguityError("more than one control matching "+description)ClientForm.AmbiguityError: more than one control matching name 'username'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is only one form from the code provided and multiple username, passwords fields which is where the Ambiguous error comes from. You could use the index parameter like you did for selecting the form, something like this:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
userone = br.find_control(name="username", nr=0)
userone.value = "Myusername"
pwone = br.find_control(name="password", nr=0)
pwone.value = "Mypassword"
br.submit()
```